# Properly handling long data in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am getting a data too large problem in hibernate. that is-

> Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'FBZipLoc' at row 1
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1527)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1065)
>       at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:58)
>       at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:195)
>       ... 12 more

Is it possible automatic truncate all field's data.
or any other way to handle this problem.
but I does not want to check all field's data length because I have more then thousand of fields.

Comment: you have to 
1. write manually a function which checks length and truncate data if possible before saving data.
2. expand column space in DB.

Comment: Use an aspect to intercept if there are a ton of columns and fields

Comment: I have thousands of fields so I can't write a function and call from each field.

Answer (score 4):

From what I know there is really no way for Hibernate or MySQL to automatically truncate strings without you adding in the logic to handle this.  The reason why I would believe that something like this doesn't exist is that I would never want what I asked to be inserted into a database be different than what really was inserted.

I think your only options are...

1. **Change the column definitions.**  Make it a larger varchar field or maybe even a text field.  Don't spend time building a magic tool when just changing the column definition would fix this in a couple clicks.  I recommend doing this!
2. I could see you using some sort of **aspect to intercept** the setters and then adjusting the size of the string if it's larger than x length.  This would be the quickest why to handle it in your code.  If changing the DB isn't an option and you have thousands of fields this would be my next choice.
3. **Build a String util** class which can re-size your strings...

   setText(String val){this.text = StringUtil.truncate(val,size);}

**[UPDATE]**
Since you can't really update the database I would recommend an aspect to intercept String setters and check their length it might look like this (syntax may be off and i didn't test this)...

```
private static final MAX_SIZE_OF_STRINGS = 255;

@Around("execution(* your.package.*.set*(..)) && args(java.lang.String)")
public void checkAroundSetter(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp)
    throws Throwable {
    Object[] args = pjp.getArgs();
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        if (args[i] instanceof String && ((String) args[i]).size() > MAX_SIZE_OF_STRINGS) {
            args[i] = ((String)args[i]).subString(0,MAX_SIZE_OF_STRINGS) ;
        }
    }
    pjp.proceed(args);
}
```

Also, there would be some additional overhead if some layer had to check the defined column size against all the data coming in to the table on each insert.

Comment: My project almost 95% completed and I have 98 tables with 120-150 fields so I can't change my BD or column property.

Comment: Consider an aspect then to intercept and truncate the Strings.  It will be easier than a StringUtil and a whole lot less code changes.

Comment: Hibernate interceptor is, probably, much better choice in this case than AspectJ interceptors.

Comment: @Alex: agreed (+1).  I forgot about stock hb interceptors.  This will be a better choice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Hibernate interceptor](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/events.html#objectstate-interceptors) for that. It will allow you to alter your object state
right before you save it. You can easily trim your strings based on specific columns or specific types that you save.

Comment: I am not using Jboss, I am using a simple hibernate3.jar only hor hibernate.

Comment: It has nothing to do with JBoss. It's Hibernate documentation which is hosted on jboss site.

Comment: I didn't understand your last comment. Pls clarify.

Comment: @AlexGitelman let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2009/discussion-between-khoyendra-pande-and-alex-gitelman)

Answer (score 0):

You can configure MySQL to truncate data if that's what you really want:

> If strict SQL mode is not enabled and you assign a value to a CHAR or VARCHAR column that exceeds the column's maximum length, the value is truncated to fit and a warning is generated. For truncation of nonspace characters, you can cause an error to occur (rather than a warning) and suppress insertion of the value by using strict SQL mode. See Section 5.1.7, [“Server SQL Modes”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html).

However, that's not advisable for a production db.