# Get hibernate to automatically truncate data to fit column rather than throw exception

Tags: hibernate

I have a series of String based attributes in a Hibernate entity, by default Hibernate maps these to a VARCHAR(255). This isn't long enough for some values but I know I can change this using

```
@Column (length)
```

But sometimes I have the case that the data being passed to the set*Attribute* method is longer than the length I have defined, in these cases I just want hibernate to essentially do a s.substring(0,length) but instead it just throws an exception.

Is there any way that I can get it to automatically substring the data to fit. If I cannot I have to add a length check to every set method, and if I change the the length of the column in the database then update the code. This isnt a major headache but it would be nice if I can avoid this.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6882009/346561

Comment: @Jesse Webb Yes you are correct this is the same issue, but I think my question is clearer and it would be nice if an actual solution using Hibernate Interceptors could be provided.

Answer (score 0):

implement a Hibernate UserType and

```
for (... map : config.GetClassMapping())
{
    // iterate properties and set usertype to all properties with columns length set
}
```