# Way to automatically truncate a String column using JPA / Spring / Hibernate?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I'm using Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE, JPA 2.0, and Hibernate 4.1.0.Final.  I have a MySQL 5.5 column of VARCHAR(100) type.  If I save an entity whose value is larger than 100 characters, unsurprisingly, the save fails with the error

```
SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'MY_COL' at row 1
```

org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Data truncation: Data too long for column

Is there a way to set Spring/Hibernate/JPA so that if my String value is too long, the data will be automatically truncated to the maximum length?  I realize I could add code to automatically check if the String is 100 characters and then truncate the String with Java, but I wa curious if there's a less rigorous way to do this.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882009/properly-handling-long-data-in-hibernate

Answer (score 6):

Is there a reason why you wouldn't just put the truncation in your setString(String) method? It would appear that you have a domain rule that it shoudl always be truncated at 100 chars, so enforce it:

```
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name.length() > 100 ? name.substring(0,100) : name;
}
```

If that looks too difficult and verbose, and you do this all the time, why not use Spring AOP and create your own annotation?

```
@Truncate(length=100)
```

Comment: Actually, that may not be useful. It just brings the validation forward.

Comment: @Column(name="mystringcolumn", length=100)? All this does is define a Column, length 100 if Hibernate is generating you Database. It has nothing to do with validation.

Comment: I think this is nothing else than what Dave meant by "I could add code to automatically check".

Comment: Well ... it's not going to magically happen without at least some code. Adding an annotation to any set methods which should truncate seems to be about as minimal as you could possibly get.

Comment: Andrei is right -- what you included initially is what I meant by "I could add code to automatically check".  I was hoping there was some pre-packaged annotation or other directive that would allow things to get truncated without my having to write custom code.

Comment: Since everyone uses Lombok and there will be no assignment method in the class, the annotation should be for the field. How can I write an annotation as @Truncate(length=100) that it will automatically truncate the string during the set() method call.